# Python Deprecation warning

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3,and in 3.9 it will stop working.
```

These are my import statements.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import os

import pymssql

os.getcwd

os.chdir('D:\Sushil\Output')
```

How can we fix this, since I am running spyder IDE for development connecting to sql server.

Comment: Please mention the versions you are using for `pymssql`, `pandas` and `numpy`. Also mention which import statement is showing this warning.

Comment: just update every pip packages you use and try again

Comment: This is from `pymssql`. See https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/628

Comment: Yes it was from pymssql. I have upgraded to the newer version. It is working. No warning message now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using older versions of python packages. Please update these packages using the following commands in `cmd`.

```
pip install --upgrade pymssql
pip install --upgrade pandas
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the warning message was regards pymssql. I have upgraded to the newer version. It is working. No more warning message now.

Comment: This should probably be deleted as an answer since you've already made it (correctly) as a comment in your question. You might want to accept (check mark next to the number of votes) the good answer that @HamzaKrushid provided.